# Bulk commits vs Quick commits

Tags: version-control, teamwork

I know that most of you would advice to go with the strategy and methodology of the project.

However I just have a quick question, from Senior point of view, what would be better to see quick small commits from a developer, or large chunk of code pushed to the branch?

Comment: Release Early Release Often! - But ensure release isn't broken! [Eric Raymond](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/cathedral-bazaar/cathedral-bazaar/ar01s04.html)

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't really matter the size, but rather commit must be an atomic as possible. By that I mean that commit must not break the build, it should fix one specific bug, or add one specific feature and be independent from any other commits. If a feature requires a lot of code, well so be it. But usually this strategy naturally produces small frequent commits.

Comment: Can't agree more

Comment: "If a feature requires a lot of code, well so be it. But usually this strategy naturally produces small frequent commits.": Not necessarily. You can develop and test locally, and when you are confident enough you commit. You may need further commits only if you find bugs / problems later.

Answer (score 6):

There are limits, but I prefer small, atomic commits.

First, it makes things easier when you're referring to why a change was made. Second, it drastically reduces the cost of making a mistake.

Two notes of caution though:

If you're using a centralised VCS, only commit when the code builds and tests run. (If you're using DVCS, replace "commit" with "push".)

Do not implicitly refer to one commit comment from another.

```
351: pdr: Stop foo from grommiting.
352: pdr: Ooops, got that wrong, let's try again.
353: dan: New launch page.
354: pdr: Third time lucky.
```

That sort of thing. Don't do it. It's very tempting when you're committing often, because you remember the commit you did five minutes ago, and commenting starts to feel like a conversation with yourself. But control yourself. It makes no sense to the poor person, two years into your future, who does a search for the last commit on given files.